# Laravel current user in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to get `Auth::id()` in my model to check if current user has voted. How to access to current user in Eloquent Model?

Model:
    namespace App;

```
use App\User;
use App\ArticleVote;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model {
  protected $fillable = ['title', 'body', 'link'];
  protected $appends = ['votesCount', 'isUserVoted'];

  public function getIsUserVotedAttribute() {
    return !!$this->votes()->where('user_id', \Auth::id())->first();
  }
}
```

In `getIsUserVotedAttribute` method I get `\Auth::id()` of null

Comment: Do you mean you get id OR null?

Comment: Show you import pat in this class

Comment: Updated question. I get null

Comment: If you do it this way, you just have to change \Auth::id() to \Auth::user()->id. Or you can use the following globally without the Auth facade: auth()->user()->id

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Auth::user()` inside the model to get the current user.

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

```
/*
 example code: adjust to your needs.
*/
public function getIsUserVotedAttribute()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user) {
        // using overtrue/laravelFollow (for this example)
        return $user->isVotedBy($this) // this is just an example, do whatever you wanted to do here
    }
    return false
}
```

(`laravel version 5.7`)

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to call the method `getIsUserVotedAttribute()` after creating an instance of `Acticle` in a `controller` like this:

```
$article = new Article;
$article->getIsUserVotedAttribute();
```

I suggest that you pass the `user id` as parameter when defining the `method` such that

```
public function getIsUserVotedAttribute($user_id) {
     return !!$this->votes()->where('user_id', $user_id)->first();
}
```

Then you can use it in your controller like this

```
$article = new Article;
$article->getIsUserVotedAttribute(Auth::user()->id);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately i cant do like this because I use Transformers to return JSON and my index method in controller looks like this `return $this->response->withPaginator(Article::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(15), new ArticleTransformer,  'articles');`